# Finding a simplified polynomial equation through some points

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to find a basic equation that passes through 3 points.

$
f(x)=ax^b+c
\\
Where: f(1)=0,f(2)=1,f(784)=2 
$

So far I have got:

$
f(1)=0
\\ \therefore a \cdot 1^b+c=0
\\ \therefore a+c=0
\\ \therefore c=-a
\\ \therefore f(x)=ax^b-a
$

My failed attempt for $b$:

$
f(2)=1 | f(784)=2
\\ \therefore 2(a \cdot 2^b-a)=a \cdot 784^b-a
\\ \therefore 2(2^b-1)=784^b-1
\\ \therefore 2^{b+1}-2=784^b-1
\\ \therefore 2^{b+1}-784^b=1
\\ \therefore 2^{b+1}-2^{b \cdot log_2 784}=2^{log_2 1}
\\ \therefore b+1 - b \cdot log_2 784=log_2 1
\\ \therefore b - b \cdot log_2 784 + 1=0
\\ \therefore b(1 - log_2 784)=-1
\\ \therefore b=\frac{-1}{1 - log_2 784}
$

I cannot figure out how I would find $a$ or $b$ (most likely in terms of each other) (I have tried and made a bit of a mess and failed).

Little thing I made to help test: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4lldea1xiq

Comment: You haven't used $f(2)=1$, nor $f(784)=2$, which will give you two more equations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have, I simply got stuck trying to work through them, since I didn't know what point I messed that up, thought best not fill the question up with that mess.

Comment: No, it's better to include the two equations you got, so other users don't think you're hopeless.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Just added it

Comment: OK. But it looks like you did find $b$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought that, but if you check the test link, $f(2) \ne 1$ and $f(784) \ne 2$

Comment: Ah, yes, you used $\log(r-s)=\log r-\log s$, which is fallacious.

Comment: You can get to $784^b+1=2^{b+1}$, but I doubt there's any way to solve that, other than numerically. (That equation has the solution $b=0$, but it doesn't work in the original setup.)

Comment: Do you understand, Jonathan?

Comment: Are you still here?